# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null when trying to call data() method of d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a time slider at the bottom of my force layout graph and i am trying to update my graph depending on the time window that i am selecting. The section of my webpage that displays this graph can also display a matrix graph using a drop down selector. So my graph is able to update the properly depending on the time selected on the time slider. However, If i try to toggle between the matrix graph and the force layout graph a couple of times and then try to use the time slider i get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '**data**' of null

Here is the method that is called which is called when the time is updated on the slider

```
function update(checkOld, graphnodes, graphlinks) {
    // 1. Get SVG, context(scale etc)
    // 2. If redraw: Remove from SVG all - context
    path = path.data([]);
    path.exit().remove();
    circle = circle.data([]);
    circle.exit().remove();
    marker = marker.data([]);
    marker.exit().remove();
    text = text.data([]);
    text.exit().remove();
    if (checkOld == true) {
        // for (cntr = 0; cntr < graphNodes.length; cntr++) {
        // }
        graphNodes = graphnodes
        graphLinks = graphlinks
    }
    force.nodes(graphNodes).links(graphLinks).linkDistance(function(link) {
        return link.length; //link.target.size;
    }).linkStrength(function(link) {
        //if (link.className === 'red')  return 0.1;
        return link.strength;
    }).charge(function(node) {
        if (node.appId == 'com.nano.backend') {
            return -200;
        } else {
            return -1200;
        }
    }).start();
    path = path.data(force.links());
    path.exit().remove();
    circle = circle.data(force.nodes());
    circle.exit().remove();
    console.log(" ******* ****** ");
    console.log(graph.nodes);
    marker = marker //.data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .data(graph.nodes, function(node) {
            //return "arrowhead";
            console.log(node);
            return node.id;
        });
    //  marker.exit().remove();
    text = text.data(force.nodes(), function(node) {
        return "S1" + node.id;
    });
    text.exit().remove();
    path.enter().append("svg:path") // actually line is added here
        .attr("class", function(edge) {
            return "link " + edge.type;
        }).attr("id", function(d, i) {
            return "link" + i;
        }).attr("marker-end", function(edge) {
            //return "url(#" + edge.target.id + ")"; //need to match with id passed above in "marker"
            return "url(#" + "arrowhead" + ")"; //need to match with id passed above in "marker"
        }).on('click', linkclick).on('mouseover', onlinkmouseover).on('mouseout', onlinkmouseout); //Added
    circle.enter().append("path").attr("class", "node").attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) {
            return "circle"; //(d.shapetype)
        }).size(function(node) {
            return node.size * node.size * 3.14;
        })).attr("opacity", 1).style("fill", function(d, i) {
            if (d.group == compType) {
                // console.log(d.appId+ ' ' +graph.apps[d.appId]);
                return color(graph.apps[d.appId]);
            } else {
                "";
            }
        }).attr("r", function(node) {
            if (node.compId == "*") {
                return 1;
            }
            return node.size;
        }).on("click", onnodeclick).on("dblclick", dblclick).on('mouseover', onnodemouseover)
        //.on('mouseover', tip.show) //Added
        .on('mouseout', onnodemouseout) //Added
        .on("mousedown", function(event) {
            if (event.which == 3) {
                alert("right clicked!");
            }
        }).call(drag);
    marker.enter().append("svg:marker").attr("id", function(node) {
            //called for each data node added in above line before enter
            //return "M"+node.id;
            return "arrowhead";
        }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        //.attr("refX", 16.5)
        .attr("refX", function(d) {
            return markerw;
        }).attr("refY", function(d) {
            return 0; //d.size +9;
        }).attr("markerWidth", markerw).attr("markerHeight", 3).attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5"); //define shape of marker (arrow here) http://bl.ocks.org/dustinlarimer/5888271
    text.enter().append("svg:g");
    svg.selectAll(".link-group").append("text").attr("dy", "-0.5em").append("textPath").attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {
        return 8 / 20;
    }).attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
        return "#link" + i;
    }).text(function(d, i) {
        return "";
    });
    // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    text.append("svg:text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").attr("class", "shadow").attr("id", function(node) {
        return "S1" + node.id;
    }).text(function(nd) {
        if (nd.group == instanceType) {
            return "";
        }
        return nd.name;
    });
    text.append("svg:text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(function(nd) {
        if (nd.group == instanceType) {
            return "";
        }
        return nd.name;
    });
    `enter code here`
}
```

I have tried to debug the issue and have centered the problem to the following code in the update method

```
marker = marker //.data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .data(graph.nodes, function(node) {
        //return "arrowhead";
        console.log(node);
        return node.id;
    });
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my agonizingly long issue, I am relatively new to d3 and would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: The error in general means that you got something like `x.y`, and the value of `x` is `null`.

Comment: @Pointy so with respect to my program you mean the value of `graph` might be `null` .

Comment: The error should include a line number, and your browser's developer tools can also help.